# How to customize wix search bar

Tags: velo

I'm trying to build an commerce store using wix and i want to customize the `search bar` that comes with a default site template. Currently, the search works by going through the names of the products I have on the store to find matches(name of product). I want this functionality but also make an improvement by perform search based on a selection. When a user click the search box, I want a drop down of keywords that they can select. And on enter, the `search results` page will display all products on the store that contains any of the keywords selected.

For example, let's say my store sell cars and I want my `search bar` to produce a dropdown list of `CarColors` as I want user to only use the search to search for different car colors. So on click, the search bar will have as options `[red, black, blue, silver]` where a user can select one or more. If a user select `red` and `silver`, the results page should display all `red` and `silver` cars.